# Modify ASP.NET Web API deserialization process

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, asp.net-web-api, json-deserialization

I created a Webserver based on the OWIN / Katana. Currently I have problems about understanding the JSON deserialization process...

This is the simple POST-Method:

```
public IHttpActionResult Post([FromBody] Person person) {
// do some stuff
return Ok();
}
```

Now the question: Why are all Getters of the Model called by default, also if there are attributed as "JsonIgnore" or no "DataMember".

Model:

```
[DataContract]
public class Person
{
    private string firstName;

    //This property-getter should not be called
    public string FirstName{
        get {
            return firstName;
        }
        set {
            firstName = value;
        }
    }

    //This property-getter should be called
    [DataMember]
    public string LastName { get;set; }
}
```

Is is possible to change this process?

Comment: If you will decorate FirstName property with attribute JsonIgnore - getter will not be called while serialization/deserialization.

Comment: Getter is still called, also with JsonIgnore attribute

Answer (score 0):

Solved.

I detected that the getter is called during Web API model validator (see class "DefaultBodyModelValidator")